# React js app having same folder images but in ios png images showing alpha tranparency issue

Tags: android, ios, png, transparency

In React js app having one folder images use for both app Andorid and IOS. but in IOS PNG images showing alpha transparency issue.

I have opened image in IOS and fix transparency issue:
Open image in Preview app click File -> Export and uncheck alpha

After uncheck alpha its working fine in IOS. But its showing white background in Android. any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. its due to we have compress icons from tinypng website. due to its showing alpha transparency issue in IOS